# VBA get "Object required" when trying to loop through cells in ranges in arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to Make a "For Each" loop where the code will get the ranges stored in an array and loop through them, changing the color of the cell to orange if the cell is empty. 
I can enter each cell in the array, but to save space and time I have stated ranges. I can run the array through a single for loop, but then he will treat the entire range as a single value, so I try to loop through the ranges as well, looping through each cell. 
I get an "Object Required" error and I struggle to understand where I am making the mistake.

I've tried to determine different types of data types to the variables as I believe this is where the error lies, this without result.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim CellCheckList As Variant
Dim ChRng As Ranges
Dim ChCell As Range


CellCheckList = Array("E1", "I1", "B3:B8", "B9:F9", "B14:F14", "J14:J19", "B25", "C26", "B27:B28", _
                "C29", "B30:F31", "C32:C33", "B34:F35", "C36", "B37:B39", "B42:F42", "C43:C44", _
                "B45", "B48:B56", "C54:F54", "B77", "B78:B84", "C82:F82", "B88:F88", "C89", _
                "C92:C94", "B95:B97", "C97:F97", "C98")

    For Each ChRng In CellCheckList
        For Each ChCell In ChRng
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("time sheet").Range(ChCell)) = True Then
                Sheets("time sheet").Range(ChCell).Interior.Color = 49407 
            Else
                Sheets("time sheet").Range(ChCell).Interior.Color = 16772300
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: The items in your array are not ranges, they are the *addresses* of ranges - i.e. Strings and not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim rngList As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("time sheet")

        Set rngList = .Range("E1, I1, B3:B8, B9:F9, B14:F14, J14:J19, B25, C26," & _
                                "B27:B28,C29, B30:F31, C32:C33, B34:F35, C36, B37:B39," & _
                                "B42:F42, C43:C44, B45, B48:B56, C54:F54, B77, B78:B84," & _
                                "C82:F82, B88:F88, C89,C92:C94, B95:B97, C97:F97, C98")

        For Each cell In rngList

            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                cell.Interior.Color = 49407
            Else
                cell.Interior.Color = 16772300
            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ a much better method :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are quite done, just some minor changes required. Referring to each item of the `CellCheckList` array, you need to build the single ranges manually (**tested**):

```
Dim CellCheckList As Variant
Dim ChRng As Range
Dim ChCell As Variant
Dim item As Variant


CellCheckList = Array("E1", "I1", "B3:B8", "B9:F9", "B14:F14", "J14:J19", "B25", "C26", "B27:B28", _
                "C29", "B30:F31", "C32:C33", "B34:F35", "C36", "B37:B39", "B42:F42", "C43:C44", _
                "B45", "B48:B56", "C54:F54", "B77", "B78:B84", "C82:F82", "B88:F88", "C89", _
                "C92:C94", "B95:B97", "C97:F97", "C98")

For Each item In CellCheckList
    Set ChRng = Sheets("time sheet").Range(item)
    For Each ChCell In ChRng
        If IsEmpty(ChCell) = True Then
            ChCell.Interior.Color = 49407
        Else
            ChCell.Interior.Color = 16772300
        End If
    Next
Next
```